# UIViewController update itself on the fly?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

How to let a UIViewController update itself on the fly if I need to display real time data? For example, I want to display the time clock on the view. The second part increments by 1 every second. Which method should I call to let the UIViewController have a background process that automatically changes the content without explicitly refreshing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update whole `UIViewController` if you want only update clock object.

One way to update clock once in a second is to use `NSTimer`. Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003747).

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateClock:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update the whole thing, you only need to update the clock. So for example if your using a digital clock, you could do:

```
- (void)clockTimerStart{
    //call this in your viewDidLoad method

    //start the clock
    NSTimer *clockTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateClock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Then, for your `updateClock` method

```
- (void)updateClock{
    //this will be called every second while the clockTimer method is running
    //you could increment the time here. For example, if your incrementing
    //variable was named "increment"

    increment++;
}
```

Then, when you want to stop yoru clock, you could use `clockTimer = nil`